# Обобщенные методы Java. Почему extends а не implements?

Tags: java, интерфейс, generics

Читаю Г.Шилдта тема "Обобщенные методы". Там приводится такой пример обобщённого метода:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> boolean arraysEqual(T[] x, V[] y) { 
// ...
}
```

и пояснение к нему:

"... Также обратите внимание на то, что T **наследует** интерфейс Comparable. Интерфейс Comparable определен в пакете java.lang."

На сколько мне было известно, интерфейс может быть расширен (extends) только другим интерфейсом.

Почему тогда "<T extends Comparable" из приведённого выше кода - валидно? Ведь Comparable это интерфейс, а под Т подразумевается **НЕ** интерфейс, а класс например. И в пояснении написано именно: - "T **наследует интерфейс** Comparable" ? Почему extends а не implements? Подскажите, в чём логика?

P.S. Я конечно подозреваю, что "Т" !== класс ("T" это "параметр типа") может с этим связано, но если бы там написали implements, то вопроса бы не возникло.

Comment: дженерики живут по другим правилам и наследование там специфическое. это совсем не то, что наследование в классах.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976441/java-generics-why-is-extends-t-allowed-but-not-implements-t

Answer (score 2):

Все дело в самом языке. К примеру C# вовсе не указывает что он наследует, а что реализует тупо перечисляет. Если интерфейс то нужно имплементировать, а если класс то наследует. Так вот с математичкой (она же логическая) точки зрения особо разницы нет что использовать `extends` или `implements`. Вот на дженериках Java это явно заметно.